# Is it possible to have two indexes in a coldfusion for-loop?

Tags: coldfusion, for-loop

```
<cfscript>
    for(firstIndex = 1, secondIndex = 1; firstIndex > 10, secondIndex > 5; firstIndex++, secondIndex++)
        WriteOutput('First Index:' & firstIndex & 'Second Index:' & secondIndex & '<br>');
</cfscript>
```

obviously this code doesn't work, but is there a way to do this in CF or do I just have to create my own second variable in the loop and do

```
if(secondIndex > 5)
    break;
secondIndex++;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loops in CF may not have more that one index. The quickest way to do what you want is use a conditional loop:

```
<cfscript>
    firstIndex = 1;
    secondIndex = 1;
    while (firstIndex < 5 && secondIndex < 10)
    {
        WriteOutput('First Index:' & firstIndex & ' Second Index: ' & secondIndex & '<br/>');
        firstIndex++;
        secondIndex++;  
    }
</cfscript>
```

BTW, your `>` signs will want to be `<` that signs--otherwise your above code will never iterate through a single loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not like you're doing it, no. Use a nested loop.